# PHP Preg-Replace: "a period with numbers on each side"

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I'm trying to scour a csv with timecodes and subtitles, and change the timecode format.

For instance:

```
timecode_in, timecode_out, text
01:09:37.12,01:09:40.11,and we felt very close to them.
```

I need to replace all of the periods in the timecode with colons. But I need to filter it so it won't change the periods in the text.

I'm thinking there should be a way to say: "Where a period has a number on each side, replace it with a colon."

Can anybody help me with this? I have never used regular expressions before.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: @Colin Fair enough. I appreciate that sentiment. I realize StackOverflow is about learning, not about others doing your work for you. But right now I'm in crunch time trying to get this movie done, and I thought I would throw it out to the universe for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to say this are [lookbehind and lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30doq)

`(?<=\d)` is a lookbehind assertion that ensures a digit before the current position

`(?=\d)` is a lookahead assertion that ensures a digit ahead of the current position

But those digits are not part of the match!